# Community Global Header

Tags: community, partner-communities

I have created a custom community with custom home page using visulforce, but when i am trying to access community from sf global header its redirecting to standard page not the custom one that i have configured.

I have enabled the access to internal users.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks,

Dildar Hussain

Comment: Looks like this is a feature, not an issue. Tested it, didn't work. In a worst case maybe have tab to navigate to custom homepage.

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? Maybe you can post the solution to help others.